# Python: Need Assistance

Tags: python

Need assistance with program for my Introduction to Python Course:

Write a program that asks the user for a string containing their first, middle, and last names. The program will modify the input to display the initials that were entered. If a person enters “NA” as the middle name, then the program should display only the initials of the first and last name. Use the following strings to test the program:

Alfred E. Newman                 A.E.N.
John NA Smith                J.S.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    index = 0

    #first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    #middle_name = input("Please enter your middle name: ")
    #last_name = input("Please enter your last name: ")

    #first_initial = first_name[0].upper() + "."
    #middle_initial = middle_name[0].upper() + "."
    #last_initial = last_name[0].upper() + "."

    #print("Here are your initials: ", first_initial, middle_initial, last_initial)

    full_name = input("Please enter your full name (with spaces): ")
    f_i = ""
    m_l_i = ""

    for ch in full_name:
        if index == 0:
            f_i = ch.upper() + "." + " "
        if ch == " ":
            index += 1
            m_l_i += full_name[index].upper() + "." + " "
            index += -1

        index += 1

    full = f_i + m_l_i

    print("Your initials are: ", full)

main()
```

the program works, but I am having issues with adding the IF for the if the middle name is "NA"

Comment: Do your homework yourself.

Comment: You might find it easier to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) the input string. Also, I would avoid variable names like `f_i`. Use something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating character-by-character makes your problem harder. You can break the string using the `.split()` method, and use *unpacking* to get the names

```
first, middle, last = full_name.split()
```

Then it is pretty straightforward

```
middle_name = "" if middle == "NA" else  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def get_initials(name):
    """ Return initials of first, last and middle name.
    If the middle name is 'NA', return only the initials of the first and the last name.

    >>> get_initials("Alfred English Newman")
    >>> 'A.E.N.'
    >>> get_initials("John NA smith")
    >>> 'J.S.'
    """

    first, middle, last = name.lower().split()

    if middle == 'na':
        initials = first[0] + '.' + last[0] + '.'
    else:
        initials = first[0] + '.' + middle[0] + '.' + last[0] + '.'

    return initials.upper()   


full_name = input("Please enter your full name (with spaces): ")

print(get_initials(full_name))
```

A couple test runs:

```
Please enter your full name (with spaces): John NA smith
J.S.

Please enter your full name (with spaces): alfred e newman
A.E.N.

Please enter your full name (with spaces): Alfred English Newman
A.E.N.
```